# R: Count number of rows in columns for a specific value, in a data subset

Tags: r, group-by, count, subset

I'm trying now for some days to find a solution to something really simple, with no luck. Here it is:

1. I've got a data frame with a row called `RESPONSE`.
2. I'm subsetting condition A and then grouping by `Subject`.
3. I'd like to count the sum of the cases per Subject where `RESPONSE==44` and `RESPONSE==77`. However, not every subject has these, so for some subjects this sum should be 0.

I tried various commands, incl. `summarise`, `count`, `filter`. But I either get an aggregate of the cases overall for everyone, or it drops participants who don't have `77` or `44` (as opposed to assigning them a 0).

I imagine the code should look something like:

```
Condition_A <- subset(df, Condition=="A") %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  sum(df$RESPONSE==77 | df$RESPONSE==44)
```

I see other people using `sum` the same way but I get an error that all my variables need to be numeric, and the row `RESPONSE` itself is.
I'd be extremely grateful for any help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `summarise`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Condition, ~Subject, ~RESPONSE,
         "A",        1,        77,
         "A",        1,        44,
         "A",        1,         1,
         "A",        2,         1,
         "A",        2,         1,
         "A",        2,        44,
         "A",        3,         1
)

df %>%
  filter(Condition == "A") %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  summarise(
    responses = sum(RESPONSE == 77 | RESPONSE == 44, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Subject responses
#>     <dbl>     <int>
#> 1       1         2
#> 2       2         1
#> 3       3         0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I did everything exactly the same and I still get only 1x1 output, with a single value, summarised for all my participants. For some reason it just would not group by Subject. Do you have any possible suggestion?

Comment: It sounds like the `summarise` function from `plyr` is being used instead of `dplyr`. Replace `summarise` with  `dplyr::summarise`.

Comment: Million thanks! That was exactly the problem! Have a lovely evening :))))